# Google translation of words with css styled individual characters

Tags: css, character, html, google-translate

In an ongoing website development project I style all 'o' characters in a certain visible text area to a red color, using a html span tag and css, like this:

```
Questi<span class="redcharacter">o</span>n.
.redcharacter { color: red; }
```

The problem is that when I use the google website translator that I have added to the website, the span tag breaks the words and google translates the separate parts instead of the whole word ("Questi" as one word, "o" as one word, and "n" as one word).

**My question is:** *Is there a way to make the "google website translator" translate the whole word and still let me style individual characters?*

I have so far tried (without luck):

1. Searching for other ways of styling individual characters.
2. Searching for a way to "hook on" to some google translation javascript function
   so that I could remove the span tags prior to the translation. It
   would be acceptable not to have the individual characters styled in
   the translated pages, as long as the translation of the text itself
   works.

Thank you in advance, and thank you for this amazing website, it has helped me tremendously lately!

EDIT: This is the code I use to include the "Google website translator" on my page:

```
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<script>function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element');}</script>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
```

Comment: If this is an art piece or just for display headings, then maybe this approach might be acceptable, but otherwise I would not recommend it. From a usability/design perspective, having every instance of a common letter rendered in a different color is going to be hugely distracting and aesthetically unattractive. Secondly, you're butchering the semantic structure of your content. You may as well start using `<font>` tags again, as you no longer have a separation of presentation and content. Lastly, screen readers are going to break up those words just like Google Translate is doing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I do see your point. The site logo has dark red "o's" in it, and the text being styled to match this "site gimmick" is user contributed "poem-like" short texts. It actually looks quite good in my eyes :-) Nevertheless, usability and semantics is important to me, so I will probably hope for the :nth-letter() css pseudo-element to be implemented soon, and skip the styling for now, to ensure correct usage with screen readers and translation. Thanks again for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's innerHTML property to get the text inside of the textarea, then replace all occurrences of `<span class="redcharacter">o</span>` with just the letter o. Then send that text out to be translated.

```
function translate(){
    text = document.getElementById('myTxtArea').innerHTML;
    parsedText = text.replace("<span class="redcharacter">o</span>","o");
    // send parsedText to Google Translate...
    // do something with what is returned
}
```

Something like that.

**edit:**
In light of new details;
My first recommendation would be to look on Google for a different means of sending and receiving words and their translations.  One that gives you some freedom.  Looking at the code, it looks like they plant a copy of the box from translate.google.com into your page.

If that doesn't work, follow the link to the [source code](//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit) and copy the code there to your own file.  Modify that code (it's kind of a confusing read) and put it into your site.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The problem is that I don't know how to "hook on" to the "google website translate" function ("send parsedText to Google Translate..."), and I can't seem to find any answer to this when searching for it!

Comment: You do currently have it sending text to Google right? Could you edit your question to include the code you use to have the text translated?

Comment: How do you style the text in the text box? Do you have it preset, or does it do it dynamically?

Comment: The text in the text box is user input stored in a database. I use server-side script (PHP) to style the text before I present it to the user. The user can then choose to click the "translate" control from google to translate the page, and here I would like to "hook in"! I really appreciate your time on this!

Comment: That was a good tip! I haven't got the google js-code to work locally yet, but I will accept this as the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since `:nth-letter()` isn't available yet (but I hear it's coming), I would use a client side script to color all the o's red, and make sure to fire it after the translation is complete.

It might flicker, but there is no way to target individual characters with css (yet) without extra markup (which breaks the translator).

Here is a super sketchy [rumor site](http://www.bram.us/2012/04/13/css-nth-letter/) for reference :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that was an interesting read! :nth-letter() would solve my problem, although I would have to generate the css dynamically since the text I need to style is based on user input, so the positions of the characters is not known at coding time. My problem now though is that since it is the website visitor that fires the translation when using the dynamically loaded control from google (the "Google website translator" div), I dont know where to put my code for removal of the styling prior to translation. The standard case is that there is no translation, which works well!

Comment: Oh. Ok. Then I'm afraid I can't help you.